# Two instances of Diablo III inside one process?

Tags: multithreading, virtual-machine

I am wandering if it is possible, even not ever implemented, to launch two instances of Diablo III inside one process. It is a exam question: give an example that when you can use threads or processes to open an application, you choose processes. I answered if I want to open two Diablo III, I would use processes because it is more stable. However, the instructor said it is not possible to launch Diablo III by threads. I just doubt his statement, why is it impossible? Not even on a virtual machine? I think it should be at least theoretically  feasible. And answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, threads and processes are two different things.

Comment: This is not what I am asking for.

Comment: This has nothing to do with virtual machines. Virtual machines have no effect on the difference between threads and processes. The point is that a process contains one or more threads, but an application like Diablo III requires its own process. Your original answer was correct (you would use processes), but the justification was wrong. It's not because it's "more stable", it's because that's the only way it will work.

Answer (score 1):

An instance of Diablo III *is* a process.  A process cannot run *within* another process.  A process can spawn another process (and wait for termination) but they will both run in separate memory spaces.  "cannot launch by threads" doesn't make any sense.  A thread can call things like `ProcessCreate` to start a process; but that creates a separate process and separate thread(s) within that process.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. If I launch two threads in a process to call ProcessCreate() and the two processes run Diablo III, isn't it launch Diablo III using threads? You see in the questions, it asks for the situations where we can use threads and processes to launch two applications, and we choose processes. The statement here :"A process cannot run within another process." doesn't quite fit here, since any application is a process right?

Answer (score 0):

Threads only exist within a single process. While you can have multiple threads launch and wait for a process each, the processes themselves will be completely independent.

Comment: This is not what I am asking for. I do understand the fact you explained.

Comment: So then which part *aren't* you understanding?

Comment: I edited the question to more details, maybe you want to check it out again. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Each application must be a separate process. This can't change.